# calculate surface normal with random sampling of points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, approximation, random, 3d

Given a surface in $R^3$ and a point P on the surface, I want to calculate the surface normal in this point, the vector that is perpendicular to the surface.

However, I do not know the whole surface, but merely a random sampling of points on the surface.

How can I calculate a good approximation of the surface normal?

The surface is non-intersecting, smooth and roughly planar, if that matters

Answer (score 1):

1. Select some number of close points of *P*. Within some radius, or the *K* closest neighbors.
2. Fit a plane to those points using [Linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29). Possibly weigh points closer to *P* higher, using [Weighted least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Weighted_linear_least_squares).
   $$ a \cdot \left( x - x_0 \right) + b \cdot \left( y - y_0 \right) + c \cdot \left( z - z_0 \right) = 1 $$
   $$ A X = B $$
   $$ \hat X = \left( A^\intercal A \right)^{-1} A^\intercal B \\
      \textbf{or} \\
      \hat X = \left( A^\intercal W A \right)^{-1} A^\intercal W B $$

   *A* has one row for each point, minus *P*.
   *B* is column vector filled with ones.
   *X* is the vector $ \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \end{pmatrix}^\intercal $.
   $ \hat X $ is the estimation of *X*.
   *W* is a diagonal matrix with the weight of each point.
3. Calculate the normal of the plane. This is just the norm of *X* in the above equations.

Here are some papers on the subject:

- [Estimating Surface Normals in Noisy Point Cloud Data - Mitra, Nguyen (2003)](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/n.mitra/research/normal_est/paper_docs/normal_estimation_socg_03.pdf)
- [Normal Estimation for Point Clouds: A Comparison Study
  for a Voronoi Based Method - Dey, Li, Sun (2005)](http://www.geomtop.org/paper_ppt/normal.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! This is essentially what I am trying to do, but simply fitting a plane seems like a very rough approximation. Is there some way I can use the relationships between the points, such as weighting points that are closer to P higher, or weighting points that are close to each other lower? I an make up some weighting scheme, but ideally I am looking for a method that is based on geometric principles